# After a specific number of loops, my result is unexpected

Tags: r, pi

```
a <- 1
b <- 1/sqrt(2)
s <- 1/2
i <- 1 


gaus_brent_salamin <- function(n) {
  while (i < n) {

  j <- (a + b)/ 2 # benutze j da der index von der Schleife davor  benutz werden muss
  b <- sqrt(a * b)
  c <- j**2 - b**2
  s <- s - 2**i*c
  p <- (2 * j**2)/ s
  i <- i + 1
  a <- j
  }
  return(p)

}

gaus_brent_salamin(40)
```

This code should approximate pi. It works when I use small numbers, but when I use big numbers it gives back junk numbers.

Comment: What programming language is this? And, can you show examples of the input/output you use, while using descriptive variable names?

Answer (score 1):

I added a small print statement at the end of the loop,

```
print(c(j,b,c,s,p,i,a))
```

As you noted, 40 iterations is fine. 400 is not. Looking through the output, I noticed that the variable `s` was somewhat stable at around `4.569e-01`, but around the 43rd iteration it starts to change. At the 53rd iteration, it is 10 times larger and then blows up.

This indicates that either the algorithm is not stable for larger ns, or that you need to apply data types of larger precision.